# RichTextBox text content change event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox in my application. I need to handle TextChange event for this RichTextBox. There are two scenarios in which the text can change:

1. User typed something in the textbox. RichTextBox content changed.
2. Internally in the program I change the content of the RichTextBox, based on different operations that the user does. In this case the user has not typed anything new in the RichTextBox. Its just in the background that I change the RichTextBox content.

*How do I differentiate these two events seperately?*

```
void SegFileDataContentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (EditorTabcontrol.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        try
        {
            TabItem selectedTabItem = tabItemList.ElementAt(EditorTabcontrol.SelectedIndex);

            SegmentFile selectedSegFile = segFileList.ElementAt(EditorTabcontrol.SelectedIndex);

            if (!selectedTabItem.Header.ToString().Contains('*'))
                selectedTabItem.Header = selectedTabItem.Header + "*";

            selectedSegFile.DataContentChanged = true;

            //update dataContent to reflect lastest rtb.text
            RichTextBox selectedRTB = rtbList.ElementAt(EditorTabcontrol.SelectedIndex);             

            selectedSegFile.DataContent = new TextRange(selectedRTB.Document.ContentStart, selectedRTB.Document.ContentEnd).Text;                    

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SegFileDataContentChanged", "SegFileDataContentChanged Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown Exception Thrown: " + "\n  Type:    " + ex.GetType().Name + "\n  Message: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No file open", "No File Open Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```